# How can I get the value of a checkbox from a for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

My `receive()` function parses through data from a backend server and I use that data to create a `renderHTML()` function which displays the parsed data as an HTML string. I get the data to display and can also attach checkboxes perfectly fine. I am trying to get the value of questionid so that when the user clicks on the checkbox, I can use Ajax to send the values of which question was selected, which can be done by questionid. I am not sure on how to get the value of the questionid, store it, and send it through Ajax.

```
function receive() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text").value;

  var data = {
    'text': text
  };

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {

      var ourData = xhr.responseText;
      var parsedData = JSON.parse(ourData);
      console.log(parsedData);
      renderHTML(parsedData);
    }
  };
  xhr.open("POST", "URL", true);
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}

var questionid;

function renderHTML(data) {
  var htmlString = "";

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    htmlString += "<p><input type='checkbox' value='data[i].questionid'>" +
      data[i].questionid + "." + "\n";
    htmlString += '</p>';
  }

  response.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);

  var t = this;
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        console.log(this.questionid.value);
      }
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {

          var Data = xhr.responseText;
          console.log(Data);
          var parseData = JSON.parse(Data);
        };
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));

      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is doing 'questionid' here I'm not sure. You declared it without any assignment and using it as a 'data[i].questionid' properties, can you little bit explain this?

Comment: `questionid` is the name in the (name : value) pair that I am receiving from `parsedData` in my `receive()` function. I wanted to access the value of `questionid` so that I can send it to a backend server via onclick

Comment: I think we can't access value like that way "console.log(this.questionid.value);" can you try "console.log(this.value);"? Because input checkboxes no attribute like that.

Comment: console.log(this.value); outputs the `'data[i].questionid'` string but I want the value, like the actual questionid, for example, 1, 2, 3...etc..

Comment: Yes it should come like that because your code need adjust: htmlString += "<p><input type='checkbox' value='" + data[i].questionid + "'>" +
      data[i].questionid + "." + "\n";
    htmlString += '</p>';

Comment: thanks it worked! I have a question, is it possible to submit multiple values for example <input type='checkbox' value1='" +data[i].questionid+ '" value2='" +data[i].question+ '"> and then I can do something like "console.log(this.value1);" ?

Comment: Yes then you need to name the input as a array style like that: '<input name="chekboxes[]" />' then you will receive an array with checked values and you can submit. See here: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/checking-if-at-east-1-checkbox-is-selected-in-an-array-of-checkboxes/2719/3

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways in which you can achieve what you are looking for. For that, you will need to understand one of two concepts:

- bind
- closures

None of them is easy to understand for beginners but will help you vastly improve your coding skills once you get them. You can read about them [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/) and [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease) respectively.

The problem with your code (amongst other details) is that the value of i is global, and so by the time the DOM is rendered and the user can click in one of the checkboxes, all the checkboxes have the same value of i (the last one).

**bind** helps you solve this by setting an argument to the function that will always remain the same.

**closures** help you solve this by storing the value of a variable declared in a scope that is accessible only from a function that stores a reference to that variable.

Here is some code I wrote that does what you want using a most modern syntax, which I would highly recommend.

Specially, I would recommend you to read about the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API); which is a much cleaner way to make http request.

This code does what you are looking for:

```
function receive() {
  const text = document.getElementById('text').value;

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ text })
  }
  fetch("<the url here>", options)
    .then( response => response.json())
    .then( data => {
      renderHTML(JSON.parse(data));
    })
}

function renderHTML(data){
  for (const x of data) {
    const content = x.questionid;
            // i'm asuming that the response html element already exists
    response.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<p><input value="${content}" type="checkbox">${content}</p>`);
  }
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach( input => {
    input.addEventListener((e) => {
      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(e.target.value)
      };
      fetch('<the second url here>', options).then( response => response.json())
        .then( data => {

          // 'data' is the response you were looking for.

        })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: You are missing all your semicolons. At the *very* least use them if the OP uses them.